# overriding ubercart - add to cart button

Tags: ubercart, forms

I try to override add to cart button with hook form alter in custom module with this function but I got an error **Fatal error: fatal flex scanner internal error** end of buffer missed in. What can be the problem?

```
function uc_button_form_alter($form_id, &$form_state, $node) {
  if ($form_id == 'edit-submit-' . $node->nid) {
    $form['submit']['#attributes']=  array(
      'class' => 'node-add-to-cart',
      'xxx' => 'xxx',
    );
  }
};
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

In D7, below is my solution for different product classes.

```
/* Overrides the Add to Cart form text*/
if ( !empty($form['nid']) ) {
  $node = $form['nid']['#value'];
}
else {
  $node = 0;
}
if (($form_id == 'uc_product_add_to_cart_form_'.$node) and ($form['node']['#value']->type =='uc_recurring_subscription')){
   $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Subscribe');     
}

if (($form_id == 'uc_product_add_to_cart_form_'.$node) and ($form['node']['#value']->type =='credit')){
   $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Buy');     
}
```

For regular product or just one product class, this should work.

```
/* Overrides the Add to Cart form text*/
if ( !empty($form['nid']) ) {
  $node = $form['nid']['#value'];
}
else {
  $node = 0;
}
if (($form_id == 'uc_product_add_to_cart_form_'.$node){
   $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Buy now');     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function's arguments are wrong. 
See [hook_form_alter docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7).

So basically you need to rewrite your function as follows.

First, grab the correct form ID.form_alter functions don't have a $node but in some forms, full node object form is in $form.
So use the following code. You will now see at least 2 message on your messages area with form ID and array explanation of $form.

```
function uc_button_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  drupal_set_message($form_id);
  drupal_set_message('<pre>'.print_r($form, 1).'</pre>');
};
```

Now, check if the node ID you are looking for is available in the $form array. (in most cases, it's in $form['#node']). 
Now you can change the function to the real code.

```
function uc_button_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (isset($form['#node']->nid) && $form_id == 'edit-submit-' . $form['#node']->nid) {
    $form['submit']['#attributes']['class'] = 'node-add-to-cart';
    $form['submit']['#attributes']['xxx'] = 'xxx'; // we don't want  to clear existing values.
  }
};
```

However, even this implementation is not necessary. You can make use of default classes with tricky nesting if you only want to add a class to the button.

Update after 3rd comment:
Try this:

```
function uc_button_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (isset($form['nid']['#value']) && $form_id == 'edit-submit-' . $form['nid']['#value']) {
    $form['submit']['#attributes']['class'] = 'node-add-to-cart';
    $form['submit']['#attributes']['xxx'] = 'xxx'; // we don't want  to clear existing values.
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. I tried your code in custom module but it is not working. I use D6. I know that `function uc_product_add_to_cart_form` is the function I want to override. My aim is to add some additional code inside button's code to track clicks, since I am going to use ajax cart. I tried also a variation of a snippet I found here just to see if it works http://pastebin.com/btbuELMM `function xxx_uc_catalog_buy_it_now_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['submit']['#value']=  t('Yes i want one');
}` none from above works

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the form array output ? We can't code blindly :)

Comment: see the update pls

Comment: No change. To override all buttons I use `function acquia_prosper_button($element)` put inside template.php. I tried to remove it in case it fights but the html code is not changed at all.